# Cannot play Spotify and Youtube videos in Google Chrome concurrently in Ubuntu Wily 15.10

Tags: sound, google-chrome

If I pause Spotify, I can play a Youtube video. If I close the window with the Youtube video, I can play Spotify. If I play a Youtube video while Spotify is playing, there will be no audio. If I try to play a song in Spotify while a Youtube video is playing, it will say unable to play track.

How can I fix this? This is a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 install with those to programs added.

relevant output from Chrome:

`ALSA lib conf.c:3325:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1024:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave`

Comment: Are you using HTML5 on YouTube? It sounds like maybe both tabs are trying to use Flash Player at the same time. Or maybe Chrome only allows audio from 1 tab at a time?

Comment: I'm sorry if that wasn't clear. I'm using the Spotify program, not playing through Chrome. This has worked for my on other computers running other versions of Ubuntu. This is the only version of Ubuntu I've installed on this computer and I don't have another computer running 15.10 to test against. Playing multiple Youtube videos simultaneously works fine. It's using the HTML5 player, not Flash.

Comment: does Spotify is set to use pulseaudio ? if it is set to use directly alsa sound layer (alsa device is something like hw:0,0 ) , it can block soundcard for programs using pulseaudio   .

Comment: I believe both chrome and spotify use ALSA directly. They both depend on libasound2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Chrome. It needs the package `libasound2-plugins:i386` in order to play sound through PulseAudio. Installing that package fixed my issues.